# How to use html form to submit API link to get JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am creating a Package Tracking Form for a courier company.

Here is my html form

```
<h2>Track Package</h2>

<form>
  <label for="trackingno">Tracking No:</label>
  <input type="tel" id="trackingno" name="trackingno">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Company has provided the API Link

```
http://portal.activecourier.pk/api/v1/packet/00003711/status
```

When I click this link I get this data

```
{"packet_id": "0024-00003711", "consignee_name": "Nasir maqbool", "destination": "Lahore", "current_status": {"status": "Assigned to Courier", "datetime": "2020-12-27T17:55:05.414Z", "comment": null}, "statuses": [{"status": "Pickup request sent", "datetime": "2020-12-27T09:55:41.295Z", "comment": null}, {"status": "Booked", "datetime": "2020-12-26T10:13:15.333Z", "comment": null}]}
```

I want to use html form so visitor enters his package tracking # and get his package details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They usually use jquery to do this

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  const response = $('#response');
  const trackingId = $('#trackingId').val();
  let html = '';
  $('#trackingId').val('');
  response.html('Please Wait');
  $.get('http://portal.activecourier.pk/api/v1/packet/'+trackingId+'/status', function(data) {
    html += '<div><strong>Packet Id:</strong> '+data.packet_id+'</div>';
    html += '<div><strong>Consignee Name:</strong> '+data.consignee_name+'</div>';
    html += '<div><strong>Current Status:</strong> '+data.current_status.status+' at '+data.current_status.datetime+'</div>';
    let statuses = data.statuses.map((e) => {
      return e.status + ' at ' + e.datetime
    });
    html += '<div><strong>Statuses:</strong> <ul><li>'+statuses.join('</li><li>')+'</li></ul></div>';

    response.html(html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response"></div>
<input type="text" id="trackingId"/>
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: sir I use this code but it return Please Wait msg only

Comment: @HannahJames This is because the protocol of this site is https and this site does not support https. It works well if you use this code on the http protocol

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad ... I am able to get the result using your code :) Can you help me to output the current_status and statuses result as statuses are in loop